# Questions about remapping keys

Tags: keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I have a couple of questions about remapping keys *et al.*

- How to interpret the output of the command `xmodmap -pk`. I put in `xmodmap -pk | less` and try to browse for the key I am looking for. Here's a sample line from the output:

  `94         0x003c (less)   0x003e (greater)        0x003c (less)   0x003e (greater)        0x007c (bar)    0x00a6 (brokenbar)      0x007c (bar)`

As I understand, this corresponds to the entry for keycode 94. What I don't understand is why are there 7 entries against this key?  What do they mean?

- How does one find a key on the keyboard whose keycode is a given number? I'd appreciate an elegant way of doing this. For instance, there is always *this dirty trick* of punching in the keys with `xev` running... I am looking for an answer that would explain how the keycodes are assigned to the keys in this case.
- I want to remap the key with keycode 94 to `backslash` and shift + the key to `bar`.

Can you guys please help me?

Answer (score 0):

- From [this forum](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap)

Print the current keymap table formatted into expressions:

```
$ xmodmap -pke
keycode  57 = n N
```

Each keymap is followed by the keysyms it is mapped to. The above example indicates that the keycode 57 is mapped to the lowercase n, while the uppercase N is mapped to keycode 57 and Shift.
Each keysym column in the table corresponds to a particular key combination:
    Key
    Shift+Key
    mode_switch+Key
    mode_switch+Shift+Key
    AltGr+Key
    AltGr+Shift+Key

- Have you tried

  xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = backslash bar"